# No signal to monitor after driver install

Tags: 10.10, drivers, ati

After installing 10.10 I used `Hardware Drivers` (Jockey) to install the graphics driver v11.2 for my ATI HD 5770.

After restarting to activate the driver all went well and the boot screen showed up but not like the normal one the text was rough on the edges and after the boot finished the screen turned black and no signal.

I have found some forum discussions about that issue but no fix worked for me.
I use a DVI to VGA adapter and I have a View Sonic E70F CRT monitor.

[this is the last thing i see before i get a no signal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrzfS.jpg)

i found a bug report at [launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-ati/+bug/560306) take a look

- using `sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
  and the rebooted the screen came on
- after the boot or splash screen the
  desktop resolution is `1152x864`
- I can't use the CCC "catalyst control
  center":
  [image: msg popup]
- I can't enable desktop effects

I have found that my **EDID** in my monitor is corrupt and Ubuntu is not reading my monitor when I set it to defalut and gives me this error:

[image]

In windows the display is read as generic non-PnP monitor and it can live with that while Ubuntu can't. The error message is the right size when I set my display as default.

People  told me i can put refresh rates horizontal and vertical and screen resolution in xorg. Am I on the right track? How can I do that?

Comment: in  the other post that guy got his issue which is like min fixed by DVI to HDMI adapter

Comment: Did you try using a DVI to HDMI adapter?

Comment: my monitor is CRT so no way :D

Comment: Just statically set the Monitor parameters in xorg.conf or follow the boot to safe mode and configure directions from the answer below.  If you boot to windows fine, then copy those settings.

Answer (score 4):

There was a bug that had a problem with the ATI driver.  The bug has now been fixed, so if you update it should now work, although I recommend you reconfigure your xorg.conf from scratch by moving the old one:
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.bak

Link to the original bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/685682

Answer (score 1):

The issue with Ubuntu is you need to manually specify in your drivers' control panel that "This monitor needs a signal, here's the specs".

On an nVidia system that I have, I have to connect the monitor, then open up the control panel for the nVidia system, hit 'Detect Monitors', and then I can configure what resolution and other options for the monitor.  Note I've got a VGA monitor, but the same setup works for an HDMI connection (i.e. my desktop with an nVidia card connected to my 42 inch widescreen TV)

Comment: i cant see the login screen so i cant log in and play with the CCC "catalyst control center"

Comment: Then i think your issue is more than just a problem with your computer not giving your monitor a signal... perhaps the drivers broke it or did not configure itself correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hold down shift during boot to enter grub menu. Choose safemode. Now you will be able to reconfigure x.

You could try to uninstall all ati drivers before installing the driver by doing folllowing:

sudo stop gdm

sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*

sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri fglrx-modaliases

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core

sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf

sudo rm -r /etc/ati/

And then reinstall the driver. Go to system -> Administration -> Hardware drivers.

Comment: sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf and the reboot.

Comment: Reinstall the driver. Go to system -> Administration -> Hardware drivers.

Comment: i did the steps in ur answer and that only removed the drivers and installed them back again so the problem came back no signal after splash screen 
i went in to safe mod low graphics and found xorg.conf and it contains the following 

`Section "Screen"
    Identifier    "Default Screen"
    DefaultDepth    24
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load    "glx"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier    "Default Device"
    Driver    "fglrx"
EndSection
`

Comment: Try the driver from ati/amd instead. Remove all drivers again and reinstall.

Comment: Are you running 32bits or 64bits Ubuntu?

Comment: 32bits and i have tried ATI drivers tha same .
can u give me an xorg.conf configs that include my card identity and res cuz the xorg that i have is useless